# Better way of implementing the Trait pattern in Java?

Tags: java, traits

I would like to allow my domain classes to have "injectable" behaviour.

The idea is based on es4j Protocols https://es4j.eventsourcing.com/docs/master/core_concepts/domain_protocol.html

However I use AxonFramework so I need to implement it myself.

Currently the method I employ is a "protocol handler" that is based on interfaces.

A sample DomainProtocol (pseudocode)

```
public interface NameProtocol extends ProtocolBase {
    public String getName();
    public void setName(String name);

    default boolean handleNameProtocol(DomainEventMessage eventMessage){
        // pseudocode
        if(eventMessage == NameChangedEvent) setName(eventMessage.getName());
    }

}
```

The base aggregate type would then do the initialization of the handlers either based on class names or annotations.
For now it is based on `MethodHandle methodHandle = lookup.findVirtual(aggregateClazz, "handle"+interf.getSimpleName(), MethodType.methodType(boolean.class, DomainEventMessage.class));`

Interfaces unfortunately only allow public methods, which causes some internal methods to be visible outside, so I created a class `ProtocolHelper` that enforces the callers of those methods :

```
public class ProtocolHelper extends SecurityManager {
public static final ProtocolHelper INSTANCE = new ProtocolHelper();

public Class[] getCallingClasses() {
    return getClassContext();
}


public static void enforcePrivate(){
    Class[] classes = ProtocolHelper.INSTANCE.getCallingClasses();
    // 0 1 - this class
    // 2 - the protected method
    // 3 - should be a class that extends ProtocolBase (or same class as 2)
    if(
        !ProtocolBase.class.isAssignableFrom(classes[3])
        &&
        !classes[2].equals(classes[3])
    )
        throw new RuntimeException("This method can only be called by the protocol handler !");
}
}
```

and then use it like this :

```
@Deprecated
@Override
public void setName(String name) {
    ProtocolHelper.enforcePrivate();
    this.name = name;
}
```

Obviously this method is quite horrifying, however after many hours of trial and error this is the best solution I could come up with.

I try not to use reflection anywhere but in initialization, and id prefer not to make an Annotation Processor complicating the build..

It feels like Java is deliberately trying to prevent me from doing this, static abstract class are not inherited, no protected interface methods allowed, etc etc..

Is there any way to achieve what Im trying to do ?

Is there any problem with this solution that I am not aware of (other than that its "ugly" or "not kosher") ?

Comment: If you want to have a clear API, use an abstract class (without setter).

Comment: I cannot extend an abstract class, since I have to `extend AbstractEventSourcedAggregateRoot<T>`

Comment: What about `abstract class AbstractNameProtocol<T> extends AbstractEventsourcedAggregateRoot<T>`?

Comment: Then it would be impossible to implement two protocols in one class ;/

Comment: Would Java 8's `default` interface methods work?

Comment: @Bohemian I allready use those in this method, Its just that those methods should not be called outside of the class/protocol handler, and since they are interface methods they are public.